# What does shutdown look like for a kubernetes cron job pod when it's being terminated by "replace" concurrency policy?

Tags: kubernetes, cron

I couldn't find anything in the official kubernetes docs about this.  What's the actual low-level process for replacing a long-running cron job?  I'd like to understand this so my application can handle it properly.

- Is it a clean `SIGHUP`/`SIGTERM` signal that gets sent to the app that's running?
- Is there a waiting period after that signal gets sent, so the app has time to cleanup/shutdown before it potentially gets killed?  If so, what's that timeout in seconds?  Or does it wait forever?

For reference, here's the `Replace` policy explanation in the docs:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/

> Concurrency Policy
>
> - **Replace: If it is time for a new job run and the previous job run hasn’t finished yet, the cron job replaces the currently running job run with a new job run**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A CronJob has just another Pod underneath.

When a Cronjob with a concurrency policy of "Replace" is still active, the [Job will be deleted](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/6a19261e96b12c83e6c69d15e2dcca8089432838/pkg/controller/cronjob/cronjob_controller.go#L324), which also deletes the Pod.

When a Pod is [deleted](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods) the Linux container/s will be sent a `SIGTERM` and then a `SIGKILL` after a grace period, defaulted to 30 seconds.  The `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` property in a [PodSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#podspec-v1-core) can be set to override that default.

Due to the [flag](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/3b440dfd5550b13278e40975a7cba13a3f129475/staging/src/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1/types.go#L441-L443) added to the [`DeleteJob`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/933f9a469feadcb1904e9d2b7258102ea89f6c7a/pkg/controller/cronjob/injection.go#L120-L123) call, it sounds like this delete is only deleting values from the kube key/value store. Which would mean the new Job/Pod could be created while the current Job/Pod is still terminating. You could confirm with a Job that doesn't respect a `SIGTERM` and has a `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` set to a few times your clusters scheduling speed.

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation, with great links to the code.